# What will getPlatformName() return on ios apps running on Mac?

Tags: ios, macos, codenameone

ios apps can now run on Mac. What does `getPlatformName()` return in that case? I can't test this because I think that you need a new mac for this, but I saw some mac downloads for my app.

My app calls `getPlatformName()` in several places and always expects `ios` or `and`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be "ios" since the `getPlatformName()` is always hardcoded in the implementation and isn't the interesting thing to query.

The interesting question is "what will be the value of `isDesktop()`" and that's something I don't know. However, we do have an Arm Mac for experimentation and we will check. We'll try to make it return the right value and behave as a desktop app.

Comment: Does the fact that an iOS application can run as a desktop application on MacOS require developer intervention or is this option enabled by default? Is it something that can be prevented?

Comment: You can edit availability on Apple Developer. Otherwise as soon as you accept the updated license agreement at release time it is available by default

Comment: @Shai are you aware of a service similar to MacInCloud where ARM macs can be rented?

Comment: This is currently legally prohibited as far as I can tell from the license we agreed to. I can't even share any information about the machine which is pretty typical of Apple. So I'm sure no one can host it freely.